# What can I find in EMS One Souvenir Packages?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Can't find any information that would mention what are in these cases.

I know that the Dreamhack 2013 Souvenir Packages came out with a certain set of guns with Dreamhack stickers, but what do the EMS One Souvenir Packages come out with?  Are there certain stickers for it that are rarer than the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Souvenir quality weapons from the previous package, Dreamhack 2013.

The main difference is the sticker.   Each Souvenir case opened from any EMS: One Tourney game will have three stickers, a default Gold ESL Wolf (random position), and both team's foil stickers (dependent on the game it dropped from).

[image]

For example, the weapon above came from a package dropped during the Group Stage match between compLexity Gaming and Clan-Mystik.  This means you'll get three guaranteed Foil stickers (random positions) on the gun, comprised of: a Gold ESL Wolf, Team A's foil sticker, and Team B's foil sticker.